# Entity Extraction/Validation in Bot Composer

Tags: azure, bot-framework-composer

I have a composer text input task with the following settings. I'm making a bot testing the capabilities of Luis integrations with a bot. The issue I'm facing is not the entity recognition itself; rather the entity validation on the input task for the entity. I only notice this when using a text input task and have the entity validation working for other tasks (specifically datetime).

[Current Entity User Input Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcMjN.png)

To illustrate my issue, here are two current behaviors of the bot:

**WAI:** *I say something like "I want to make an appointment and my contact number is (800)-234-5678". This not only triggers my intent model and skips the user input question where I ask for the user's phone number (seeing as they provided one already) and the conversation.phoneNumber variable is (800)-234-5678*

**Not WAI:** *I say something like "I want to make an appointment and my contact number is abc". This triggers my intent model as desired but skips the user input question where I ask for the user's phone number (because it thinks they provided one already) and the conversation.phoneNumber variable is abc. Ideally, this is where I would think validation would happen and it would ask the question "What is a good phone number for our office..." seeing as abc isn't a phone number.*

For reference, this is the documentation I'm following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-define-advanced-intents-entities

I considered a regex validator as an option because phone number is such a trivial entity that can be easily defined, but something more complex/diverse (such as geographic location, currency, etc) would be better handled by whatever dictionaries Microsoft has in place for built-in entities. I can see the raw data when I type in an utterance that shows no entity is being picked up (so SOMETHING is working in the background). I'm just curious if I can make use of that functionality in a bot composer task.

As I said before, this is working fine when validating if a user entered a date/time on a separate task; I'm hoping there's a feature for this for other built-in, text-based entities in the bot composer.

I assume that whatever built-in entity recognition that Microsoft has for their built-in entities here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-entities is vastly superior to whatever regex I can come up with, and some type of built-in validation would be handy for more complex bots.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If the issue you are facing is: *..the entity validation on the input task for the entity**  Could you please provide the code/task or whatever you are using specifically for the issue you are describing, so it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response! Are you looking for something other than the image provided in the hyperlink "Current Entity User Input Task"?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused but how do we see the **validation rules** on the provided image?
Isn't it the **entity validation** what you mentioned as the issue? Sorry, if I haven't completely understood the question..

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear, but it's on the far right image at the very top. And I'll say this, I have used user input tasks for DateTime in the past where the entity validation is working without having anything listed in the validation rules. So I'm hoping there's something similar to this for the other entities when using a user input text task.

Comment: Also, it looks like I got a response from Microsoft's team and the correct validation rule I have to add is @phonenumber != null (really simple, not sure why that's not in their documentation for this at the moment), but this is working for me now!